# Toggle visibility of content in web app

Tags: javascript, toggle

This question is not about how to toggle a div. But instead how to toggle visibility in a big web app. My web app needs only to run on Chromium (Webkit). The problem I have is probably more related to infrastructure and best practices, and I wonder if anyone has experience with this.

My app runs on node-webkit, which means all files are local, and loading is quick. To feel really snappy, I add all content to the DOM I possibly can. I want to stay away from state changing my app with Javascript, so no `$('.view-projects').addClass('visible');`. Because it will get messy really soon, and I feel it's not really the task of JS.

Instead the approach I have chosen works like this.

```
// javascript sample (I actually code in CoffeeScript)
// catch all click events on elements with data-trigger attributes
app.on('view:addProject', function () {
  // add a class to the root view
  $('#app').addClass('view-addProject');
}):
```

Markup:

```
<!-- markup sample -->
<div id="app">
   <div class="projects">
      <div data-trigger="view:addProject"></div>
      <div>etc.</div>
   </div>

   <div class="addProject">
     etc.
   </div>       
</div>
```

Css, used as the state machine:

```
app.view-addProject .addProject {
   visibility: visible;
   display: block;
}
```

What I want to know is if other people have tried something like this, have good experiences with other approaches etc. Or maybe I am missing something, I feel I am getting myself in trouble with dynamic content.

Note: I can't simply use show/hide, since my elements use `display: -webkit-flex/-webkit-box;` etc.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your CSS, shouldn't it be #app.view-projects .addProject {...} ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle visibility, here are some alternative approaches:

- Control state by changing CSS via the CSSOM
- Change state by changing data- attributes
- Change state by changing DOM nodeNames